# empty log file when running batch ftp?

Tags: loops, batch-file, logging, ftp

I'm running a batch file that runs a ftp connection.
Everything is working; 
my only problem is that I want to see the result of the ftp session.
I have done this:

```
    @echo off
    (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("IP.txt") do (
       ping -n 1 %%a |find "TTL=" >nul 
       if errorlevel 1 (echo %%a failed) else (echo      %%a passed
start c:\ftp -s:test.txt %aa) 
    )>%%a.txt
    )>output.log
```

but this only creates me an empty txt file.
If I do the same command not in a batch file - it's working

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: By calling `start` you are running `ftp` in a new command shell. The redirection is happening in the current `cmd` shell, not the new one.

Comment: You wrote `%aa` instead of `%%a` once...

Comment: What is empty finally -- `%%a.txt` or `output.log`? I guess both: `%%a.txt` is empty because of `start` as per the [above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489275/empty-log-file-when-running-batch-ftp#comment64380501_38489275); `output.log` is empty because the redirection to this file is overwritten by `> %%a.txt`...

Comment: this is all type error in the massage .   the %%a.txt is empty. it create me the files 10.0.0.1.txt (for example) but it stay empty .   the output.log is OK I get the pass\failed with the IP address.

Comment: the %%a.txt file is empty - he create the files but noting inside of if..